How to give an ID to a visitor React
I created a game for restaurants where all visitors can spin a wheel and win something. I need to ensure that each visitor (without authentication) can play only once, even if they come back. I tried implementing it myself using IP address + user agent, but it didn’t work well, and local storage/cookies can be bypassed with private browsing. I found Fingerprintjs, but the free plan’s accuracy was too low, and it had a lot of collisions. The premium plan is also too expensive. Do you have an idea on how I can assign an ID to a visitor? Thank you so much. By the way, I’m using Next.js 14.
I tried user agent + address ip combinaison but it didn’t worked well ( they are both not static ), tried also cookies and localstorage ( bypass using incognito mode )

That's a tough question since I think there is no specific unique identifier for that. A combinaison of user-agent + browser specific + cookies + language + timezone + device type etc...
In a nutshell you could create a function that combines all those in a specific format to create a "pseudo-unicity" for visitors.
As far as I know, if you have to rely on clients, you can't have a 100% bypass-proof solution. That's the best i can give you.
Kindly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This would make it significantly harder (though not impossible) to bypass:
visitor-identifier.tsx
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { kv } from '@vercel/kv';

interface VisitorData {
  fingerprint: string;
  lastPlayed: number;
  playCount: number;
  ips: string[];
}

export async function checkVisitorEligibility(ip: string, userAgent: string) {
  // Create a base fingerprint from IP + User Agent
  const baseFingerprint = `${ip}:${userAgent}`;
  
  // Check all recent plays for this IP
  const ipPlays = await kv.get<string[]>(`recent-plays:${ip}`) || [];
  
  // If too many plays from this IP in short time, block
  if (ipPlays.length > 10) { // 10 plays per IP per day
    return {
      canPlay: false,
      reason: 'Too many attempts from this IP'
    };
  }

  // Look for similar fingerprints
  const similarPlays = await kv.scan(0, { match: `visitor:${ip}:*` });
  
  // Check if this looks like a repeat visitor
  for (const key of similarPlays.keys) {
    const visitorData = await kv.get<VisitorData>(key);
    if (!visitorData) continue;

    // If exact match found within 24h
    if (Date.now() - visitorData.lastPlayed < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
      return {
        canPlay: false,
        reason: 'Please wait 24 hours between plays'
      };
    }
  }

  // Store the play
  const visitorKey = `visitor:${ip}:${Date.now()}`;
  await kv.set(visitorKey, {
    fingerprint: baseFingerprint,
    lastPlayed: Date.now(),
    playCount: 1,
    ips: [ip]
  }, { ex: 86400 }); // Expire after 24h

  // Add to recent IP plays
  await kv.lpush(`recent-plays:${ip}`, Date.now());
  await kv.expire(`recent-plays:${ip}`, 86400);

  return {
    canPlay: true
  };
}

route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
import { checkVisitorEligibility } from '@/utils/visitor-identifier';

export async function GET() {
  const headersList = headers();
  const ip = headersList.get('x-forwarded-for') || 'unknown';
  const userAgent = headersList.get('user-agent') || 'unknown';

  const result = await checkVisitorEligibility(ip, userAgent);

  return NextResponse.json(result);
}

Anti-Abuse System Approach

Rate Limiting by IP

Tracks number of plays per IP address
Blocks if too many attempts from same IP
Expires tracking data after 24 hours


Pattern Detection

Stores play history with IP and user agent
Looks for similar patterns in recent plays
More sophisticated than simple matching


Time-Based Restrictions

Enforces 24-hour cooldown
Tracks play attempts with timestamps
Auto-expires old data


Key Advantages

More resilient to basic bypassing attempts
Balances user experience with security
Self-cleaning data through Redis expiration
No client-side storage needed



While this isn't 100% foolproof (no solution really is), it creates enough friction to discourage most casual attempts to bypass the system while remaining fair to legitimate users.
Implementation
To use this in your game component:
game-wheel.tsx
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function GameWheel() {
  const [eligibility, setEligibility] = useState<{
    canPlay: boolean;
    reason?: string;
  } | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkEligibility() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/check-eligibility');
      const data = await response.json();
      setEligibility(data);
    }

    checkEligibility();
  }, []);

  if (!eligibility) {
    return <div>Checking eligibility...</div>;
  }

  if (!eligibility.canPlay) {
    return <div>{eligibility.reason || 'You cannot play at this time'}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your wheel game component */}
    </div>
  );
}

This solution is more practical than complex fingerprinting because:

It's simpler to implement and maintain
Has fewer false positives
More predictable behavior
Better performance
No client-side dependencies


G E N I U S, wtf bro G G.
